# The issue with embedded images, google images proxy, ...?

Tags: gmail

My app sends html email with embedded images  (data uri scheme) to address like *@gmail.com.
All available for me desktop clients show mail correctly. But when I use web interface some images (not all) are broken.

I have got the following information as result of my investigation:

1. The issue is observed not only chrome, but on FF and IE too.
2. Gmail for the web interface replaces values of  **src** attribute of embedded  images from  **data uri scheme** to **http url** for loading images from google proxy servers.
3. In my case Gmail uses two external servers for loading images: **gm1.ggpht.com** & **mail.google.com**
4. All images are loaded properly from server **gm1.ggpht.com** with status 200 without any redirection to another location.
5. All images which tries to load from **mail.google.com** are broken. Response headers from **mail.google.com** have 302 status (redirection) with location like **https://gm1.ggpht.com/...**
6. An attempt to open new location in browser returns response with status 403 (Forbidden)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? Thanks.

Comment: As I know - no. I tried to investigate it as help my colleagues and I don't know further results.

Answer (score -1):

The address was blocked by the Proxy server on the network you use.

Comment: English please,